# I try to download a picture from a website using the F12 command but the quality of the image goes down once it is saved on my device

Tags: html, svg, webp

I try to download this image

https://resume.io/r/v8H4jljHC

using the F12 command, in which i got a .webp and a .svg file, i try to combine those two image to no avail.

So the picture in the website is scalable when you zoomed it, but once you download it, it is not, which i assume because the website split the image into 2 files which is the .webp and .svg that i talk about, what can i do to get the high quality scalable picture downloaded to my device?

Comment: print screen, or you really need to download? ?

Comment: At least for me in Chrome, the image on that site is not scalable, but has the exact same dimensions as the webp file that you get via the Network tab. The SVG file that you see is the site's logo, and the SVG in the form of a base64-encoded data URL is just the so-called "skeleton" that is shown during page load, bevore the webp is laoded.

Comment: https://ssr.resume.tools/to-image/ssid-v8H4jljHC-1.webp?cache=ef149df843&size=2000 this is your file. I'll Recommend using the snipping tool in your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this link instead:

https://ssr.resume.tools/to-image/ssid-v8H4jljHC-1.png?cache=ef149df843&size=2000

I modified the URL to give a png instead of a webp, and to set the size to 2000px. You can modify further if you need